# MSTest or NCover test results in bamboo?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mstest, bamboo, ncover

What are the possibilities to get nice detailed test coverage reports with MSTest or NCover results in bamboo build?

Is there any integration between Bamboo and Visual Studio 2008 in terms of test results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd love to get the MSTest output myself, Bamboo 3 and VS2010. As I recall there's an option for NCover straight out of the box....

I'd have a fiddle running MSTest from the commandline and looking at the output (use the /resultsfile flag to control where the results go) But you might have done that and seen only the usual test result output.

I have tried - but there seems to be an ourtanding bug with getting Bamboo to pick up the results: http://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-8230 seem to be be working on it within the past week. Amused to see they consider it 'minor'!

I can confirm that it doesn't matter what you put for the path to the test results file, it always logs that it is looking in the base working directory - but even if you redirect output there, Bamboo still doesn't find it...